# Speedup Mysql Query on bulk update

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to update records like

```
update table abc set marks='15' 
where rollno='432423' and pcode='ABC234';
```

almost 10,000 queries.

My table has 1,00,000 records.
and I need to update 10,000 records. it take hours
how can i speed it up. i am using INNODB

any way to speed this up.

Comment: If you have a composite index on `(rollno, pcode)` it should be about as fast as possible.

Comment: @Barmar for an individual query, yes.  the problem is getting rid of the need to do 10000 separate updates

Comment: Could horizontal partitioning and vertical partitioning be helpful for this case?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is to insert records to another table and use that to update, something like:

```
create table def like abc;
# optionally drop unneeded columns: alter table def drop foo, drop bar;
insert into def (marks, rollno, pcode) values
    ('15','432423','ABC234'),
    ('16','432424','DEF567'),
    ...
    ;
update def join abc using (rollno,pcode)
    set abc.marks=def.marks;
drop table def;
```

If the update itself is still slow, make sure abc has a composite index on (rollno, pcode).

Answer (score 0):

For any solution, definitely have `INDEX(rollno, pcode)` (either order is ok)

Plan A.  This might run 10 times as fast, simply because of the transactional overhead:

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 UPDATE ...
 UPDATE ...
 UPDATE ...
 ...
 COMMIT;
```

Plan B:  Use a single statement.  This assumes you have only 3 columns in the table and (rollno,pcode) are the composite `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
INSERT INTO ABC (rollno, pcode, marks)
    VALUES
    ('432423', 'ABC234', '15'),
    ('2342345', 'qwer', '99),
    ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        marks = VALUES(marks);
```

Plan C:  See ysth's answer.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and discuss the data and the processing a bit more -- there may be other shortcuts.